# AppleScript: Cutting images in the half?

Tags: applescript, image-manipulation, cut

Is it possible to cut an image in the half using AppleScript and save them seperately?

Answer (score 7):

It would be easier to use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). This saves the left half as `input-0.png` and the right half as `input-1.png`:

```
convert input.png -crop 50%x100% +repage input.png
```

This saves just the right half as `right.png`:

```
convert input.png -gravity east -crop 50%x100% +repage right.png
```

`+repage` removes metadata for the old canvas size. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/.

You can install ImageMagick with `brew install imagemagick` or `sudo port install imagemagick`.

Comment: Definitely recommended. You can even run this in applescript via `do shell script`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Image Events, which comes with Mac OS X to crop an image if you don't have access to a scriptable image-editing application (as in Photoshop). To get the dimensions of the image just use something like the following...

```
on GetImageDimensions(TheFile) -- (file path as string) as {width, height}
    try
        tell application "Image Events"
            launch --we have to launch Image Events before we can use it
            set theImage to open TheFile
            set theImageDimensions to dimensions of theImage
            set theImageWidth to item 1 of theImageDimensions
            set theImageHeight to item 2 of theImageDimensions
            return {theImageWidth, theImageHeight}
        end tell
    on error
        return {-1, -1} // just in case something goes wrong
    end try
end GetImageDimensions
```

...and the command to crop the image is as simple as

```
crop pathToFile to dimensions {cropWidth, cropHeight}
```

If, by chance, you have Photoshop, then cropping is handled differently:

```
crop pathToFile bounds {cropLeft, cropTop, cropRight, cropBottom}
```

There is more to the command but those are the required parameters. Other applications will most likely have a different implementation (probably more like Apple's). Just select your image-editing app of choice, and peruse the Dictionary to see how it works.